# Could I upload arduino code to Arduino with VS Code

Tags: arduino, visual-studio-code, sodaq-mbili

Is it possible to upload Adruino code to my SODAQ mbili board with VS code and see a serial monitor?

- VS code version: 1.6.1
- OS version: Windows 10 [Version 10.0.14393]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it possible at least on Ubuntu, but I suppose similar procedure should work on other OS. Instructions and files to download can be found on [Github](https://github.com/fabienroyer/VisualStudioCodeArduino).

The instructions doesn't cover bringing up serial monitor, but you can just download and use any other terminal program, like [putty](http://www.putty.org/), [Realterm](https://sourceforge.net/projects/realterm/), or any other of your choice.